# Git Issue after update to Mac catalina OS : xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

After updating Mac OS to the latest version (Mac Catalina) I am unable to run the command of GIT. When I try anything I will get this below error

```
 xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to find the solution for this by a simple and single command which installs the software again which is required to run the GIT command using the terminal.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Run the above command on terminal and popup window open to install the software just follow the setup.It should work

Comment: this is not the solution

Comment: This work in my case ... Can you post which work in your case